# How to create a lag binary variable based on the values of another variable, that doesnt change values once a specific value in a group occurs?

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
ID  visit  Switch
1    1       0
1    2       1
2    1       1
2    2       0
3    1       NA
3    2       1
3    3       0
3    4       0
4    1       1
```

I desire to create a sort of lag variable where for those with multiple visits, once switch is 1, values afterwards will always be 1, once switch is 0 and other values continue to be 0 or NA, values afterwards will always be 0, and those with NAs or only 1 visit will be set as NA.

What I'd like the resulting variable is below.

```
ID  visit  Switch NewVar
1    1       0      NA
1    2       1      0
2    1       1      NA
2    2       0      1
3    1       NA     NA
3    2       1      NA
3    3       0      1
3    4       0      1
4    1       1      NA
```

I tried the following below, but it doesnt seem to work for those who have more than 2 visits

```
dtmults = dt %>% distinct(ID,visits) %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(n()>1) %>% arrange(ID)

dt %>% 
filter(ID %in% dtmults$ID) %>% 
arrange(ID, visits) %>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
mutate(var = Switch, var2 = lag(switch), var3 = var2) %>%
fill(var3,.direction="down") %>% rename(NewVar = var3)
```

my problem is that for those like ID == 3, the results look like this

```
ID  visit  Switch NewVar
3    1       NA     NA
3    2       1      NA
3    3       0      1
3    4       0      0
```

what exactly should I do to make sure once switch ==1 for an ID, all the values of Newvar in the future visits is also 1 regardless of what value it could be? I was thinking of creating a rownumber variable and in the cases where the rownumber where Switch is != 1 is higher than the rownumber where Switch==1  then NewVar for those rownumbers will be changed to 1. but I am not really sure how to code that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want the cumulative maximum of a lgged `Switch`, grouped by ID, with leading `NA`s preserved. Unfortunately, `cummax` doesn't deal with `NA`s, so we can write our own version:

```
cummax_na = function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
  if(!na.rm) return(cummax(x))
  if(all(is.na(x))) return(x)
  # check for leading NAs to keep
  first_non_na = match(TRUE, !is.na(x))
  x = dplyr::coalesce(x, -Inf)
  result = cummax(x)
  if(first_non_na > 1) result[1:(first_non_na - 1)] = NA
  result
}

dt = read.table(text = 'ID  visit  Switch NewVar
1    1       0      NA
1    2       1      0
2    1       1      NA
2    2       0      1
3    1       NA     NA
3    2       1      NA
3    3       0      1
3    4       0      1
4    1       1      NA', header = T)

library(dplyr)
dt |> mutate(result = cummax_na(lag(Switch, 1, default = NA)), .by = ID)
#   ID visit Switch NewVar result
# 1  1     1      0     NA     NA
# 2  1     2      1      0      0
# 3  2     1      1     NA     NA
# 4  2     2      0      1      1
# 5  3     1     NA     NA     NA
# 6  3     2      1     NA     NA
# 7  3     3      0      1      1
# 8  3     4      0      1      1
# 9  4     1      1     NA     NA
```